# Convert ArrayList to JSONArray

Tags: arrays, json, arraylist, hashmap

This is my ArrayList

```
ArrayList< HashMap < String,String> > list =  new ArrayList<>();
```

which holds hashmap.

How to acquire all the hashmaps in Plain JSONArray?

Comment: this is `org.primefaces.json.JSONArray`?

Comment: @alibttb this is  org.json.JSONArray

Comment: this is not available in standard java nor in jee, what library contains this class? @Vaibhav Kadam

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can do something like this,

```
ArrayList< HashMap < String,String> > list =  new ArrayList<>();
```

and then just pass List object to JsonArray like this

```
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(list);
```

thankew!

Comment: in Gson 2.8.2 we dont have this one yet.